# 2D-filter algorithm

Tags: image-processing, filter, convolution

Is there anyway to do this faster? I want to reduce the O(N^2) complexity to something lower. Note: The filter kernel is rotational symmetric around N/2.

```
for(unsigned int k=N/2;k<source.getHeight()-N/2;k++)
    {
    for(unsigned int l=N/2;l<source.getWidth()-N/2;l++)
        {

        for(unsigned int m=0;m<N;m++)
            {
            for(unsigned int n=0;n<N;n++)
                {
                dest(l,k).red  +=p_kernel[m][n]*source(l+n-N/2,k+m-N/2).red;
                dest(l,k).green+=p_kernel[m][n]*source(l+n-N/2,k+m-N/2).green;
                dest(l,k).blue +=p_kernel[m][n]*source(l+n-N/2,k+m-N/2).blue;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about convolution theorem. It basically fourier transform of your image and kernel multiplied and then the result reverse transformed. Search it, there are tons of sites with example code.

Comment: So fftw would do it. But then I need to zero-pad my kernel to make it the same dimension as my image or?

Comment: It might be necessary for the calculation of FFT depending on the symmetry but in the end it will amortize itself. You can't really tell without measuring. For small sizes of kernels there are implementations that take advantage of SIMD hardware and fall back to FFT.